# Pop!_OS will not play sound from iMac speakers

Tags: audio, macintosh, pop-os

I am new to this community, so please tell me if the question I'm asking is off topic and would be better suited to a different stackexchange.

I'm on an iMac 18,3 (27-inch late 2017) running macOS that I am planning to switch to Linux. Research showed me that Pop!_OS was a nice distribution for beginners/novices, so I flashed it to a USB and booted it up (after trying it out on a VMWare Fusion virtual machine).

A few quick checks showed me my camera was working, but when I tried playing sound from various sources (including the Test Sound you can use from the System Settings), nothing worked. I tried installing pavucontrol, which told me that sound was being outputted, but although the volume was at full and I was listening carefully close to the computer, I couldn't hear any sound. This lead me to wonder if I'm missing some drivers for my iMac speakers...

I tried looking, but couldn't find any such drivers. I also tried checking if it was an issue with my Pop!_OS boot by flashing first Manjaro GNOME and then Ubuntu 20.04 to the USB drive and booting up; both of them loaded nicely but sound still didn't work on either.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Any help to get the sound working would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.